# Where does Render function in CustomValidator obtain the attributes from?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I extended CustomValidator to insert a `<small>` tag instead of the default `<span>` tag used by CustomValidator. I currently use the following code to do this.

```
public class MyValidator : CustomValidator
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.RenderBeginTag("small");
        base.Render(writer);
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }
}
```

However, this just puts the `<span>` tag inside a `<small>` tag.

```
<small>
    <span 
        id="ContentPlaceHolder1_MainForm_CustomAliasValidator"
        class="error"
        style="visibility:hidden;">
        Alias contains invalid characters.
    </span>
</small>
```

So it seems that I need to get the attributes of the `<span>` tag and inject them into `<small>`. However, `writer` is the only argument available in the function `Render`. As far as I know, `HtmlTextWriter` is only a class for rendering html contents. Where does `base.Render()` get those attributes from and how can I use them in my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [WebControl.Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.render.aspx) tells us that it calls [WebControl.RenderBeginTag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.renderbegintag.aspx), [WebControl.RenderContents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.rendercontents.aspx) and [WebControl.RenderEndTag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.renderendtag.aspx). You've only overriden `Render` to output a wrapping tag, without changing any of the base behavior.

You should be able to override the [WebControl.TagKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tagkey.aspx) property to return `HtmlTextWriterTag.Small` to change your `<span>` to a `<small>` tag.

To answer your question, `RenderBeginTag` (which in your case outputs the original `<label>` tag) first calls [WebControl.AddAttributesToRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.addattributestorender.aspx) which calls [HtmlTextWriter.AddAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter.AddAttribute.aspx), those attributes will then show up on the next call to [HtmlTextWriter.RenderBeginTag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter.RenderBeginTag.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. That worked! I kept thinking that `Render` was a function inherited from `BaseValidator`, but `BaseValidator` actually overrides it from `WebControl`, which I didn't notice.

Comment: By the way, I think you misspelled `RenderBeginTag`.